# CSS3 Scroll Into Page Without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it were possible to create a scrolling animation akin to [**this**](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/DjmJe) without jquery? CSS3 seems to have similar viewport features such as [**this one**](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/) and it definitely has ways to animate elements.

Also somewhat related, to make a CSS3 animation play more than one time. I assume it would have something to do with removing and re-adding the class but that seems uneccesary and there's probably an easier way.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wna95/)

```
var start = document.body.scrollTop;
var target = document.getElementById('myElement').getBoundingClientRect().top; //Where we're scrolling to
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var d = target - document.body.scrollTop; //Distance to go
    document.body.scrollTop +=
        (
            Math.min( //Ease in/out
                Math.abs(d) + 10,
                Math.abs(start - document.body.scrollTop) + 10
            ) * ( //Direction
                d / Math.abs(d) || 0
            ) / 10
        ) || clearInterval(interval) || 0; // If done, clearInterval
}, 20);
```

Also, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: Okay, while that is super useful in-and-of itself for scrolling the page to top (definitely will use it for that), is there a way to replicate the slide-in effect in the linked fiddle using some sort of use of this to check distance into page?

Comment: That would be `document.body.scrollTop`.